# php convert admin input to php array

Tags: php, arrays

For my website i am trying to add special dates in a backend textfield something like this:

```
06/28 > 5:00-23:00
06/29 > 9:00-12:00, 13:00-18:00
```

And then the output has to be:

```
$exceptions = array(
'06/28' => array('5:00-23:00'),
'06/29' => array('9:00-12:00', '13:00-18:00')
 );
```

This is what i have at this point:

```
$list = $tab_one['special_days']; // import list
$list = explode(PHP_EOL, $list); // split after new line
foreach($list as $item) {
$item = explode('>', $item); // split after ">"

print_r(explode(',', $item[));
}
```

After this i am stuck. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is that actually your exact code? `print_r(explode(',', $item[));` Because clearly there is a typo and I would think it should throw some syntax error.

Comment: @domdom  It is a typo, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$list = $tab_one['special_days']; // import list
$list = explode(PHP_EOL, $list); // split after new line

// At this point I will assume that you have a line like
// '06/28 > 5:00-23:00' in each list item 

$finalArray = []; // To store the array

foreach($list as $item) {
    $item = explode('>', $item); // split after ">"
    $finalArray[$item[0]] = explode(',', $item[1]);
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```

Note that the items exploded from `$item[1]` have not been trimmed so might have whitespaces.

Comment: I think its better to explode with `, ` instead of  just `,`.

Comment: With that logic, it's better to explode first time with ` > ` as well :)

Comment: Thanks @Starx and Frayne Konok for the help. I'n not sure how to get to the final array as in my example yet but i will try.